# Django template tag inside sorl.thumbnail tag

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

when I use external images it works fine:

```
{% thumbnail "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/files/logo.png" "40x40" crop="80% top" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

But when I change first line to:

```
{% thumbnail "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/{{ field.value }}" "40x40" crop="80% top" as im %}
```

And `{{ field.value }}` is string `files/logo.png` for sure, it doesn't work any more. Is it possible to use Django tags inside thumbnail template tag and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `thumbnail` tag interpret `{{ field.value }}` literally.

How about using [`add` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#add)?

```
{% thumbnail "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/"|add:field.value "40x40" ... %}
```

Check whether `field.value` is a valid string.

Comment: @Goran, Check whether `field.value` contains a string by print that in other place. (`field.value = [{{ field.value }}]`)

Comment: Yes it is string ` files/logo.png `

Comment: Still the same, maybe I need to try with custom filter

Comment: @Goran, How about populate `img_url` attribute of `field`, then use `field.img_url` instead of making a new tag. (filter will not work if `add` didn't work for you)

Comment: finally working on the custom tag I find that {{ field.value }} is a <FieldFile: files/logo.png> not just a string. So writing {% thumbnail field.value "40x40" ... fix the problem. My fault, sorry!

Comment: @Goran, Thank you for the feedback. I updated answer accordingly.